# homebrew octave can't find gfortran in mavericks

Tags: octave, homebrew, gfortran

I've installed octave and gcc via homebrew.  Neither install returned any errors but when I try and run octave I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libqrupdate.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've done brew update, upgrade, and all that.  Brew doctor only returns messages about ownership of man directories which I think is unrelated

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:
    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
```

Any ideas?  Other posts I've seen have suggested unlinking/relinking gcc, but that doesn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 3):

brew reinstall qrupdate

After the update to gcc 4.9.1 the path has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get fortran on OSX mavericks until I did

brew reinstall gcc49 --enable-fortran

That gave me /usr/local/bin/gfortran-4.9. Then I manually created a symlink for it

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gfortran-4.9 /usr/local/bin/gfortran

Answer (score 0):

After much searching for a solution, this worked for me:

```
brew install gcc49 --with-fortran
```

I found that this installed gfortran49 as "gfortran-4.9" and "gfortran" was tied to my previous installation of gfortran48. Therefore, I went back and uninstalled gfortran48 as such:

```
brew remove gfortran
```

Then I reinstalled gcc49:

```
brew reinstall gcc49 --with-fortran
```

Seems to have worked.